# Can a renderbuffer be copied without being attached to a framebuffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I am writing a renderbuffer class, and need to define the copy constructor. I also have a framebuffer class that allows you to attach textures or renderbuffers to it. Does OpenGL allow you to copy renderbuffer data from one to the other without first attaching it to a framebuffer and reading from / writing to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, renderbuffers are pretty useless without being attached to an FBO.

The only way to copy them would be to `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` between one draw buffer and another. If this ability did exist, you might see something like `glBlitNamedFramebuffer (...)` in the [Direct State Access](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/direct_state_access.txt) extension, but alas, it does not.

Is your complaint that you do not want to disrupt the state of your FBO in order to copy the contents? DSA solves that sort of thing ordinarily, but since this is not something DSA covers, you will have to take care of any binding state restoration yourself.

Comment: I just feel as if a renderbuffer should stand on it's own, and should not rely on a framebuffer to do copying and reading. Just like the texture doesn't. Am I misunderstanding the renderbuffer?

Comment: Renderbuffers can stand on their own, but you literally cannot do anything with them until they are attached to FBOs. Textures, on the other hand, do useful things even when they're not attached ;)

Comment: Hmmm, that sucks. So, I guess the answer is to just disable copying then?

Comment: You could establish a dummy FBO that you can use for the purpose of copying RBOs.

Comment: That's true, I could. Might do that. It's better than having no copy at all. Thanks.

Comment: The main thing you can do with a renderbuffer without attaching it to an FBO is allocated storage for it, using `glRenderbufferStorage()`. You can also query some state, using `glGetRenderbufferParameter()`. And delete it, of course.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Like I said, useless unless attached to an FBO.